# Unknown top and bottom padding in panels

Tags: 7, panels, theming

I'm using the panels module in drupal 7. I'm having some problem with the css in panels. I've removed the top and bottom padding in my custom css but there still appears to be some padding. How can I remove it?
I have give the id "leftpane" and made the following CSS

```
#leftpane {
    margin: 0px;
    padding:0px 20px;
    background:#17532E;
    border-radius:17px;
    float: left;
    }
```

How do I remove the unknown top and bottom padding?

Answer (score 0):

## leftpane {

```
margin: 0px;
padding:0px 20px !important;
background:#17532E;
border-radius:17px;
float: left;
}
```

Add !important rule to override existing padding

Comment: its not working :(

Comment: Hey can you post reference url your are working on, So i can check and update you

Comment: I worked it out. The problem was with the margins in the <p> tag. I had overlooked that. Thanks anyway =]